# Are Gradients of Radial Functions parallel?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For two radial functions $f(R)$ and $g(R)$ defined on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, is $\nabla f$ always parallel to $\nabla g$? Since both functions are constant around each circle $C_r(0)$ centered at the origin, aren't the gradients parallel to the inner or outer normal vectors on each circle of radius $r$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Given a differentiable radial function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, there exists a differentiable function $h: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=h(x^2+y^2)$. Namely, $h(t)=f(0,\sqrt{t})$.

Therefore, using the chain rule, we see that $\nabla f(x,y) = \big(2x\cdot h'(x^2+y^2), 2y\cdot h'(x^2+y^2)\big)$.

So the gradient of $f$ is always pointing away from (or towards) the origin (because it is of the form $(cx,cy)$, with $c = 2h'(x^2+y^2)$). Moreover the magnitude of the gradient is always the same along any circle of fixed radius (it is equal to $2rh'(r^2)$ at $(x,y)$ whenever $x^2+y^2=r^2$).